# Is there any way I could add a loader in html till the PHP code works?

Tags: php, html, css

I have a PHP file named `sample.php`, and it has this code :

```
<?php
$transactionId = $_GET['id'];

$url = $transactionId;
header("Location: $url");
?>
```

And sometimes when I open this page, it takes some time to process, so I think adding a loading icon would help the user know that the page is processing, and he/she doesn't need to exit the page. So I created this HTML code snippet, which is of building a CSS loading icon. -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.loader {
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid rgba(89,59,0,100);
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite; /* Safari */
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 30%;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

/* Safari */
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="loader"></div>
<h1>Loading Gateway<br>Please wait...</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Is there any way, I could merge this HTML code into my PHP file (`sample.php`) so that the user sees the loading icon (the HTML code) until the PHP doesn't open the URL?

---

I've tried building this (below code) myself, but turns out the PHP segment doesn't execute/run. All I see is just the loading icon (HTML) and nothing happens :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>

.... /*whole styling here*/

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="loader"></div>
<h1>Loading Gateway<br>Please wait...</h1>

<?php /*php code starts here - the problem is this doesn't execute at all...*/
$transactionId = $_GET['id'];

$url = $transactionId;
header("Location: $url");
?>

</body>
</html>
```

---

Can you suggest any changes I should do? Or anything I did wrong?

Thanks a lot for reading!

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** PHP code is executed from the Backend, not the Frontend. So you can not put a loading animation (Frontend) while waiting for PHP to execute (Backend) because the Backend always run first. You need to use Javascript + Ajax to do so. Also, the header function `header("Location: $url");` can only be executed at the top of the file, before any output has been shown.

There are a few very important concepts you should focus on to better understand why what you're asking can not be achieved directly:

**1. Backend/Frontend**

PHP runs on your Backend (server). HTML/CSS and the loading animation run on the user Frontend (browser). Since the Backend code always runs BEFORE it is shown to the Frontend, you can not place a loading animation while PHP is being executed within a single page.

How this is solved is with Javascript and ajax calls.

The full flow is:

- PHP renders the initial Page (without the operation that takes a lot of time)
- HTML/CSS is rendered to the browser, together with the loading animation
- JAVASCRIPT calls a new instance of the Backend via Ajax
- PHP runs the long script and passes the result back to the Javascript
- JAVASCRIPT updates the page removing the loading or doing anything else you need to do.

You need to have a look at Javascript and Ajax to proceed this way, you can find a lot of resources online.

**2. Header Functions**

Header functions in PHP must come before ANY output. So you can not use `header("Location: $url");` in the middle of your HTML. This is because a header is the first instruction that the Server sends to the Browser.

If you're simply looking for a redirect made from the frontend, you can use either a META or a Javascript `location.href`

Answer (score 1):

I have created below code for your reference or learning purpose. you can use it according to your need.

I have also added sleep function at PHP end so you can check the loader because at my end it will not take time because of no server side processing.

**HTML/JS Side Code**

```
<style>
#loader {
    border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-top: 16px solid rgba(89,59,0,100);
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite; /* Safari */
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 15%;
}

/* Safari */
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes spin {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
</style>
<form method="GET" action="action.php" onsubmit="submit_form();">
    <label>
        Transaction ID:
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="id" value="https://google.com.pk" />
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<div id="loader" style="display: none;"></div>
<script>
function submit_form()
{
    document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "";
}
</script>
```

**PHP/Backend Code:**

```
<?php
sleep(2);
$transactionId = $_GET['id'];
$url = $transactionId;
header("Location: $url");
?>
```